# scipy sparse matrices as an input for petsc4py

Tags: python, scipy, petsc

I can't seem to find a way how to efficiently load scipy sparse matrices, e.g. [`csr_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html), into a petsc4py matrix, e.g. `PETSc.Mat().createAIJ`. I found [this thread](http://lists.mcs.anl.gov/pipermail/petsc-users/2012-May/013379.html), but I'm not able to apply it.

I would also appreciate a pointer where this stuff is actually documented. The examples in the  `demo` directory only explain a part, and I can't see any docstrings.

Comment: What exactly have you tried, and how has it not worked? I don't have `petsc4py` on my system, but the instructions in your link seem to me pretty straightforward to follow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your link says that to create a sparse matrix in PETSc, you should use a command like this:

```
PETSc.Mat().createAIJ(size=(nrows,ncols), csr=(ai,aj,aa))
```

According to [this](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-3.1/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatCreateSeqAIJWithArrays.html), the `ai`, `aj` and `aa` are, in PETSc-speak:

```
> i - row indices
> j - column indices
> a - matrix values
```

These are equivalent, respectively, to the `.indptr`, `.indices` and `.data` attributes of a `scypy.sparse.csr_matrix`, see the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) for details.

So, if your link is right, the following should work:

```
>>> from petsc4py import PETSc
>>> import scipy.sparse
>>> csr_mat = scipy.sparse.rand(1000, 1000, density=0.001, format='csr')
>>> petsc_mat = PETSc.Mat().createAIJ(size=csr_mat.shape,
...                                   csr=(csr_mat.indptr, csr_mat.indices,
...                                        csr_mat.data))
```

Unfortunately, I cannot test it myself.

Comment: This completely answers my question. You also lifted my confusion about documentation because the `Mat().createAIJ()` function obviously calls the PETSc function (easily readable code) which is indeed documented. I just didn't realize that this function call is the direct call of the PETSc function.

Comment: @RafaelReiter You can actually look at the source code of petsc4py [here](https://code.google.com/p/petsc4py/source/browse/), the function `createAIJ` is [here](https://code.google.com/p/petsc4py/source/browse/src/PETSc/Mat.pyx#242). It seems to be a little bit more complicated than that, a `Mat_AllocAIJ_CSR` which I haven't been able to find gets called, so I am not really sure what goes on under the hood. But if this works for you, then it works for you...

Comment: You're right, it's not that simple. I thought I'd seen `MatCreateSeqAIJWithArrays` a few hours ago in the code, but I didn't. Do you have any hint how to come up with the right way to use all petsc4py functionality beside the demos?

Comment: I found the call hierarchy: `Mat_AllocAIJ_CSR` is in `src/PETSc/petscmat.pxi`, and it calls `MatAnyAIJSetPreallocationCSR` in `src/include/custom.h`, which calls various PETSc functions, e.g. `MatMPIAIJSetPreallocationCSR` which is actually documented in the PETSc documentation. Phew...

Comment: Some one know how to get an parallel solver for a sparse sistem with petsc4py ?