# petsc4py: Creating AIJ Matrix from csc_matrix results in TypeError

Tags: python, numpy, petsc

I am trying to create a petsc-matrix form an already existing csc-matrix. With [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442632/scipy-sparse-matrices-as-an-input-for-petsc4py) in mind I created the following example code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
import math as math
from petsc4py import PETSc
n=100

A = sp.csc_matrix((n,n),dtype=np.complex128)
print A.shape
A[1:5,:]=1+1j*5*math.pi

p1=A.indptr
p2=A.indices
p3=A.data
petsc_mat = PETSc.Mat().createAIJ(size=A.shape,csr=(p1,p2,p3))
```

This works perfectly well as long as the matrix only consist of real values. When the matrix is complex running this piece of code results in a 
`TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('complex128') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'`. 
I tried to figure out where the error occurs exactly, but could not make much sense of the traceback:

```
petsc_mat = PETSc.Mat().createAIJ(size=A.shape,csr=(p1,p2,p3))  File "Mat.pyx", line 265, in petsc4py.PETSc.Mat.createAIJ (src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:98970)
File "petscmat.pxi", line 662, in petsc4py.PETSc.Mat_AllocAIJ (src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:24264)
File "petscmat.pxi", line 633, in petsc4py.PETSc.Mat_AllocAIJ_CSR (src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:23858)
File "arraynpy.pxi", line 136, in petsc4py.PETSc.iarray_s (src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:8048)
File "arraynpy.pxi", line 117, in petsc4py.PETSc.iarray (src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:7771)
```

Is there an efficient way of creating a petsc matrix (of which i want to retrieve some eigenpairs later) from a complex scipy csc matrix ?

I would be really happy if you guys could help me find my (hopefully not too obvious) mistake.

Comment: So the dtype for `p3` is complex, right?  Doesn't `PETSc` say anything about specifying a `dtype`?  I'm guessing it initializes some array (`iarray`?) and copies data from `p3` to it.  If it was initialized as `float`, that copy would produce the error.

Comment: http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Sys/PetscComplex.html  I wonder if your PETSC is configured for COMPLEX as described on this page?

Comment: Thank you guys! I had troubles getting PETSc to work, so I configured it more than just once and in the last run I obviously forgot the option `--with-scalar-type=complex`. This is what i should have done: Either check the log file `$PETSC_DIR/arch-linux2-c-opt/conf/configure.log`. Or take a look at the reconfigure-arch-linux2-c-opt.py. There you can find all options you used to configure PETSc. Now since I added the option to the reconfigure script and ran it, everything works perfectly fine. Sorry that I bothered you guys.

Comment: @SchwartzRichard Could you turn that comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I had troubles getting PETSc to work, so I configured it more than just once, and in the last run I obviously forgot the option `--with-scalar-type=complex`.

This is what I should have done:

- Either check the log file `$PETSC_DIR/arch-linux2-c-opt/conf/configure.log`.
- Or take a look at the `reconfigure-arch-linux2-c-opt.py`.

There you can find all options you used to configure PETSc. In case you use SLEPc as well, you also need to recompile it. Now since I added the option (`--with-scalar-type=complex`) to the reconfigure script and ran it, everything works perfectly fine.