# Fast eigenvectors finding on a HPC using Qutip and slepc4py

Tags: python, scipy, mpi, eigenvector, qutip

I am doing some numeric simulations of quantum computation, and I wish to find the eigenvectors of a big hermitian matrix (~2^14 rows/columns)

I am running on a 24 core/48 threads XEON machine. The code was originally written with the help of the Qutip library. I found out that the included `eigenstates()` function only utilizes a single thread on my machine so I am trying to find a faster way to do that.

I tried using `scipy.linalg` `eig()` and `eigh()` functions as well as `scipy.sparse.linalg` `eig()` and `eigh()` but both seem slower than the function built in Qutip.

I've seen some suggestion that I might get some speedup from using slepc4py, however the documentation of the package seems very lacking. I cant find out how to convert the numpy complex array to a SLEPC matrix.

```
A = PETSc.Mat().create()
A[:,:] = B[:,:]
# where B is a scipy array of complex type
```

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('complex128') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It seems that your question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525041/petsc4py-creating-aij-matrix-from-csc-matrix-results-in-typeerror You will have to recompile PETSc and SLEPc and build-install petsc4py and slepc4py... If you are only interested by low energy pure quantum states, you will be interested by options  EPS_SMALLEST_MAGNITUDE of EPSSetWhichEigenpairs() and EPSSetDimensions() in combination to EPSType like EPSARNOLDI or EPSLANCZOS.

Comment: By the way, [scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html) may also prove helpful...

Answer (score 1):

The eigensolver in QuTiP uses the SciPy eigensolver.  How many threads are used depends on the BLAS library that SciPy is linked to, as well as whether you are using the sparse or dense solver.  In the dense case, the eigensolver will use multiple cores if the underlying BLAS takes advantage (e.g. Intel MKL).  The sparse solver uses mostly sparse matvec operations which are memory bandwidth limited, and thus are most efficient using a single core.  If you want all eigenvalues then you are basically stuck using dense solvers. However, if you need only a few., Such as the lowest few eigenstates, then sparse is the way to go.

Comment: Hi paul, thanks for the fast response. Using num[y.show_config()
blas_mkl_info:
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    library_dirs = ['/cs/labs/doria/oryonatan/anaconda3/envs/qutip/lib']
    include_dirs = ['/cs/labs/doria/oryonatan/anaconda3/envs/qutip/include']
    libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
I see that MKL is installed, however when using the eig functions, I still see in top that only one thread is being used, is that normal? when I tried using matlab eig function, all the cores were involved.

Comment: Answering myself : it seems like qutip is not set to use the maximum amount of cores in mkl. manually setting mkl to 24 solved the problem.
import ctypes
mkl_rt = ctypes.CDLL('libmkl_rt.so')
mkl_get_max_threads = mkl_rt.mkl_get_max_threads
mkl_rt.mkl_set_num_threads(ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_int(48)))
this gave me a big performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a simpler way to use all the cores , it seems like qutip didn't tell mkl to use all of the cores.
in my python code,I added :

```
import ctypes
mkl_rt = ctypes.CDLL('libmkl_rt.so')
mkl_get_max_threads = mkl_rt.mkl_get_max_threads
mkl_rt.mkl_set_num_threads(ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_int(48)))
```

this forced Intel mkl to use all the cores, and gave me a nice speedup.

(answer from [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283112/using-mkl-set-num-threads-with-numpy))

Comment: If your using the Anaconda Python distribution then there are convenience functions in the mkl module.

Comment: I am using anaconda. are you referring to https://docs.continuum.io/mkl-service/ ? I tried `import mkl` but got `ImportError `

Comment: Huh.  Always seemed to work for me.  On my install, mkl also uses all threads automatically.  Also does the same on several computers at work.  Not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: Might be that I am running on a slurm cluster, and the cpu allocation is dynamic. Maybe when anaconda was installed there were less cores available.